# A quick way to transform a multi-dimensional byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using C# Winforms.

I have a grid, a [,,] byte array, and I am enumerating through it to reduce the value of each byte in this array.

Concentrating on the particular snippet that follows, is there a quicker and more effective way to do this?

```
        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_HEIGHT; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < GRID_WIDTH; y++)
            {
                grid[x, y, 0] = (byte)(grid[x, y, 0] / factor);
                grid[x, y, 1] = (byte)(grid[x, y, 1] / factor);
                grid[x, y, 2] = (byte)(grid[x, y, 2] / factor);
            }
        }
```

n.b. The value of `factor` is 4 in this example.

Thanks!

Comment: _Here you can grid is_ -- is that supposed to be English?

Comment: Why not using the `Bitmap` class and `LockBits` which provides you with a direct access to the raw image pixels? Using `unsafe` code and pointers you could manipulate the image in a very fast and efficient way. Here's a good walkthrough: http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx

Comment: @barmar - thanks.  A bit offensive but thanks

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, I know this. But without going through the reasons why i am at this stage I want to concentrate on the byte level - thanks though

Comment: There are always reasons why we end up in *such stages*. But once we realize that there are better ways to achieve our initial goal it's usually a good idea to pursue them. In your question you are asking if there is a quicker way to perform your task and I already answered you: yes, there is a quicker way using a Bitmap and the `LockBits` method to manipulate the raw data. Is there something else you would like to know?

Comment: @darin Thanks for your comment. If I had not mentioned 'pixel' you would not have offered that solution would you?  Your answer does not tell me anything I do not know already.  Thanks for the lecture but your answer is not pertient for ME :)

Comment: Yes, of course that I would not have offered that solution if you had not mentioned the word `pixel`. On the other hand how do you expect to get pertinent answers if you are hiding your actual goal and what exactly are you trying to achieve :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov My friend you are quite right.  Your answer is a good one but not for this scenario.  I have taken your advise and removed the word 'pixel'.  You have helped me out before so your input is always worth listening to...

Comment: I would recommend you updating your question by providing more details about your exact scenario and goal if you expect to get pertinent answers. At its current stage I don't think that your question can be answered.

Comment: please help to me to understand that? Whilst I agree with you that no one has come up with any solutions I am not sure how to phrase it differently. I am using a 2 dim byte array.  I cannot use anything else. I have seen bytes array manipulated with pointers but never with a multi-byte array.